# how to sort list according to another list of different length(need to be very efficient)?

Tags: python, list, performance, sorting, indexing

I have a list(say list1) containing some data sorted according to a score.
Now I need to sort a subset of data according to their score which is stored on list1.

e.g.
l1 = array([14552, 15284, 7058, ..., 431, 5158, 11071]) has length 12876

l1 contains the data ordered according to their score(calculated from a given expression in the exercise)

l1 has no duplicates

l2 has length according to a specific filter on the data(that could be elements that are positive etc.,)

I need to print the elements in l2 according to their score
Obviously, the list lengths are different.

I have tried list comprehension but that is not efficient. I need the sorting to be less than 1s.

Can I still use zip for lists of different lengths? If I use sorted how can I define the key

Comment: Post some example input and expected output. Also what code have you tried so far?!

Comment: The time it takes to sort a list depends more on the size of the list than on the particular algorithm used.  Depending on the size, it may be impossible to sort in under a second, or any remotely reasonable sorting algorithm may be able to finish in time. That said, look at the `key` argument for either the `sort` method or the `sorted` function

Comment: list1 = array([14552, 15284,  7058, ...,   431,  5158, 11071]) has length 12876, list2 has length 50 and i need to sort these 50 elements according to where they appear in list1

Comment: Do not add additional information in the comments.  [Edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/58665587/edit) your question.  Please provide a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: Please add a complete example for list1 and for the scores into your post. Preferably also the code you already tried. Now your question doesn't have enough detail to know what you are asking.

Comment: Should we assume list1 has no duplicates? If so, specify it in the question. If not, which index should be used when a value occurs at more than index?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Whenever you tackle a problem like this, break it down into sub-problems.  The first obvious sub-problem is: how do I *quickly* find out where in `list1` a given element is?  The answer to "how do I quickly find something?" is usually "have it in a dictionary".

If you make a dictionary that tells you the rank (i.e. list1 index) of each score, then sorting scores according to that rank becomes trivial.

```
def sort_b_by_a(a: List[int], b: List[int]) -> None:
    """
    Sort list b (in place) according to rank in list a.
    """
    # Build dict of score -> rank.
    rank: Dict[int, int] = {}
    for i in range(len(a)):
        rank[a[i]] = i

    # Sort, using the rank as a comparator.
    b.sort(key=rank.get)
```

Building the dict is O(a) -- you need to scan all of the first list, but crucially you only need to do it *once*.  Sorting the second list is O(b log b) since accessing the dict is O(1) and a basic sort is N log N.

Comment: This solution asymptotically optimal in time, but not in auxiliary space. You could build a set of the elements from `b`, and then only insert a rank into the dictionary if the corresponding value is in that set. That way you would use O(b) space instead of O(a) space.